# Change order of list

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Current List

[CurrentList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viUHq.jpg)

```
Access     Autocad     Burger 

Layout     Photoshop   Sandwich

VisualStudio
```

I have used a boxed view and edited source like below to get three columns

```
<xsl:when test="$Position mod 3 = 0">
```

But the  order of items needed is like this

```
 Access       Layout       VisualStudio 
 Autocad      Photoshop 
 Burger       Sandwich
```

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this?

This is part of xml

```
<xsl:template name="NewTRJumbo" ddwrt:ghost="">
    <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Position mod 3 = 0">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="NewTR">
                <xsl:with-param name="Collapse" select="$Collapse"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="EmptyLine" select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="NewTR">
                <xsl:with-param name="Collapse" select="$Collapse"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
    <td width="1.5%">

    </td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Could you provide your source XML?  Your current XSLT (or at least a bit more of the relevant portion)?

Comment: Thank you for augmenting your post, but we still have no idea what the original XML or the XSLT involving that `xsl:when` look like.

Comment: Thank you.  That's good information, but it's still not quite far back enough.  Could you locate a template that contains `<xsl:call-template name="NewTRJumbo">` and share that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an XML document of elements, for example, something like this

```
<items>
   <item>Access</item>
   <item>Autocad</item>
   <item>Burger</item>
   <item>Layout</item>
   <item>Photoshop</item>
   <item>Sandwich</item>
   <item>VisualStudio</item>
</items>
```

And you want to group them into 3 columns, but with the items running top-to-bottom first, rather than left-to-right. You current test of `$Position mod 3 = 0` is partially along the right lines, but you are actually starting a new row each here, and so end up going left-to-right.

One thing to mention is your use of this line of code

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
```

It looks like you are simply iterating over the elements, and trying to output a closing **tr** tag after every third one. XSLT is a functional language, so you need to approach with a different mind set, and do things differentially than you would in a normal procedural language.

Firstly, you need to find the number of rows you will beed to output

```
<xsl:param name="columns" select="3"/>
<xsl:variable name="items" select="count(/*/item)"/>
<xsl:variable name="rows" select="ceiling($items div $columns)"/>
```

i.e The rows is the total number of items divided by the number of columns.

Then, you need to select the first item of each row, which is straight-forward because these will be the first 'n' items in your list (Note the use of the **mode** because the final XSLT will have two templates matching the **item** element)

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &lt;= $rows]" mode="row"/>
```

Within the template matching the starting items, you then need to output the current item, and the following sibling items which are in the row

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::item[position() mod $rows = 0]"/>
```

The only other thing to consider is adding a blank cell to the end of the some rows. This can be done by calculating the number of remaining items compared to the total items

```
 <xsl:variable name="lastItem" select="(position() + $rows * ($columns - 1) - $items)" />
 <xsl:if test="$lastItem > 0">
     <td colspan="{ceiling($lastItem div $rows)}"></td>
 </xsl:if>
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="columns" select="3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="count(/*/item)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="ceiling($items div $columns)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &lt;= $rows]" mode="row"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::item[position() mod $rows = 0]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="lastItem" select="(position() + $rows * ($columns - 1) - $items)" />
             <xsl:if test="$lastItem > 0">
                 <td colspan="{ceiling($lastItem div $rows)}"></td>
             </xsl:if>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the XML shown at the beginning of the question, the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Access</td>
       <td>Layout</td>
       <td>VisualStudio</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Autocad</td>
       <td>Photoshop</td>
       <td colspan="1"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Burger</td>
       <td>Sandwich</td>
       <td colspan="1"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```